# Cheap privacy oriented cell phones

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone, security

What are cheap (<200 USD) and privacy oriented cell phones ?

I am looking for the phones just for calling and sms messaging. I consider phones with and without operating system, or I can buy one of both types. But I do not accept situation when my OS is linked to Google like classic Android does. Is there Android version that is not preinstalled with Google services ? What are the alternatives for Android ? Can I buy any cell phone and reinstall choosen OS ?

I have heard that Nokia 3310 is good way but it is easily to break with fake BTS attack.

Then, any smartphone have operating systems that make possible to attack our device with many new ways. I learned about BlackBerry which one was privacy oriented. But probably already working with United States duties. And recently produce cell phones with preinstalled Google version of Android... Blackphone is too expensive...

I think to buy an old Nokia 3310 for some special situations and one cheap and safe smartphone with some safe OS for everyday use. What do you think ? Should I buy Nokia 3310 from some people (used) who have got it 15 years ago or can I buy one brand new (old version of 3310 but not used one) from aliexpress (from Chinese) ? They sell brand new Nokia 3310 (and it is not a new version of Nokia 3310 which is widely being sell).

Comment: If a particular smartphone has an unlocked or unlockable bootloader and has a supported community of developers you can install a ROM or at the very least root the device in order to remove all Google services. Depending on location, you might be able to purchase a phone that doesn't have any pre-installed.

Comment: Thanks for comment, so I would focus on bootloader then. Do you recommend any of the manufacturers (while concerning about privacy ?). I have read Xiaomi is violating privacy using backdoors. Any other brands ?